# How to determine which mouse button (e.g. LeftButton) is just released?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, mouseevent

I can easily check which button is currently in the Pressed state or Released state. For example, to check if the `LeftButton` is currently released, I can use:

```
void mouse_event_handler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
    {
        // left button is released
    }
}
```

My question is that: **How can I determine which mouse button (e.g. `LeftButton`) has just recently changed its state from Pressed to Released?** The above method will fail to determine this as it will also be true irrespective of which button, `MiddleButton` or `RightButton`, was previously released (i.e. it only check the current state). I am not sure `C#/WPF` natively support this. I want something like:

```
if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Just_Released)
```

---

**P.S.:** I know a way to work around by using an extra flag when the mouse button is down, and check this flag afterwards.

Comment: I think your flag, with perhaps a background timer, is the only way to go about it. There's just no reason for the built-in functionality to have this behavior, and it would incur rarely used overhead anyway. Good question though. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ChangedButton property of the MouseButtonEventArgs class

```
if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
{
    // Only occurs when the Left button is released
}

if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
{
    // Occurs everytime a button is released (doesnt matter which one) AND the left mouse button is in released mode
}
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.changedbutton(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yay! Good find. +1. herohuyongtao, if this works for you, do be sure to mark this as the answer. Something like this could be very handy.